# Ionic 4.0.2 can't start blank project

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

im using ionic 4.0.2 behind proxy il try to execute  thi commande 
`ionic start ProjectName blank` for creating a new blank project and it's generate an error 
[image: Error ionic generated]

npm commande are executed successfully proxy configured
 help me to resolve this issue

Comment: you need to add HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY env variable and attach the helper package. https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html#using-a-proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had resolved this issue in Windows something like this:

- Goto system setting -> environment variables -> system variables ->
  click “new” button
- Give name "HTTP_PROXY" as variable name and your company proxy in
  value.
- Again create new variable by clicking "new" button in system
  variables section.
- Now give variable name "HTTPS_PROXY" as variable name and your
  company proxy in value.

All the best.

Comment: when i add the tow variables i must add username and password in the url .?

Comment: I just googled and found that in some cases we need username and password. So you please try with username and password.